# R confusion heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, confusion-matrix

I have created my first confusion heatmap using the code I found [here](http://www.findnwrite.com/musings/visualizing-confusion-matrix-in-r/).

As I result I got a very nice plot with an "increasing" diagonal showing that the predicted and actual data are closely related. 
Now, when I look up other confusion matrices, all of them show a "decreasing" diagonal and I'm wondering whether I should adapt my plot in that way (and if so: how?).

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, R displays a heatmap with the row names ordered from bottom to top, rather than top to bottom.

[Here's how to change the ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854721/r-mirror-y-axis-from-a-plot)