# Other good ways to display picture from a matrix? (other than image())

Tags: r, image, matrix, plot

Say, I have a feature vector `vec`, which is actually a picture (stretched). To show it, I am using the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5638462/688080): `image(matrix(vec,nrow=height,ncol=width),axes = FALSE,col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))`, but because the origin is at the bottom left corner so the picture is rotated 90°. I think I can move the origin too but R should have a function like `imshow` in MATLAB which is more appropriate and direct for showing a picture without the need of configuring so much, while `image()` is for visualizing a matrix. So, is there such a function? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us your vec?

Comment: @Ali the size of the picture is 64x64 so the dimension is 4096. The vector is here http://pastebin.com/Pnz7p0Ac

Comment: ziyuang: tip for reproducibility: use `(1:64), seq(), runif(), rnorm()` etc. to compactly generate a sample vector, just give us a general idea what we're dealing with. Post that here not on pastebin.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684942/image-vs-ggplot-how-to-plot-color-legend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transposing your matrix by `t()` is the solution:

```
vec = runif(4096)
vec[1:500]=0
v = matrix(vec,nrow=height,ncol=width)
image(v,axes = FALSE,col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

[image]

```
image(t(v),axes = FALSE,col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

[image]

Or to flip it:

```
image(t(v)[, nrow(v):1],axes = FALSE,col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

[image]