# Color cells of a matrix with RGB

Tags: r, colors, matrix, lattice, self-organizing-maps

Is it possible to draw a color matrix using `levelplot` function in the R package `lattice`?
I must color each cell with an `RGB` function.

The color matrix must be like below and i need to color each cell like rgb(1,0.8,0.9) etc..

[image: Color matrix]

I need this because i have to implement `self-organizing-map` algorithm for color classification. i am not allowed to use built-in kohonen/som functions or som classes.

Comment: Why don't you use image() function? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310597/r-are-there-convenient-way-for-displaying-a-picture-from-a-matrix-other-than/13311266#13311266

Comment: it is possible; why do you have doubts?

Comment: if it is possible can you show me how?

Comment: Is it homework (there's a tag for homework)? Does it need to be lattice? For both base graphics and ggplot solutions come to my mind immediately...

Comment: yes it is a project.lattice is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Have look at [Murrel: (2011) Raster Images in R Graphics](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf)

It gives an excellent explanation how to do such things in base R or in grid.

Answer (score 0):

This shows you how the rgb colors are encoded in the result from rainbow() and how levelplot will handle that argument to col.regions:

```
str(  rainbow(100)) 
# chr [1:100] "#FF0000FF" "#FF0F00FF" "#FF1F00FF" "#FF2E00FF" "#FF3D00FF" ...
```

The red, green and blue arguments range across 0 to FF and the transparency value is FF, so this produces a single band across the range of values:

```
levelplot(matrix(1:100, 100), region=TRUE, col.regions=rainbow(100) )
```

And this gives you a  (horrible) color matrix:

```
levelplot(matrix(1:10000, 100), region=TRUE, col.regions=rainbow(100) )
```

Comment: can i change the color of a random cell with this approach? i mean i want to change the color of [3,3]