# Plot an image from the matrix in R

Tags: r, image, matrix, png

I need to plot the image from the matrix. I have the 4 by 4 matrix `mat`.
I have tried to plot the image from the matrix as was recomended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638462/r-image-of-a-pixel-matrix).

```
mat <- matrix(c(255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 255,255,255,255, 0,0,0,0), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
png("simpleIm.png", width = nrow(mat) + 1, height = ncol(mat) + 1, units = "px")
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
image(mat, axes = FALSE, col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
dev.off()
```

**Update.**
Resulted image has width and height each 4 pixels. But I have the warring:

```
Warning message:
In png("simpleIm.png", width = nrow(img_new) + 1, height = ncol(img_new) +  :
  'width=5, height=5' are unlikely values in pixels
```

Could anyone please give an advice how to correct the code in order to its work without the warning message?

Comment: You may look at `?png`, where you see that the default height and width are each 480. Change them to your heart's content.

Comment: @Heroka, thanks you for comment. I have updated my code and question because the warning message was generated.

Comment: The warning happens with small height and width values as they're unusual. Why is it a problem?

Comment: @Heroka, thanks you. My test example is 4x4 martix. My work matrix has 100 colunms and 100 rows. Problem is solved.