# Effective clustering in R, outputting to other toolkits

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, statistics, data-visualization

I have a pretty big 5868 x 5868 matrix of users vs users that have values that indicate similar behavior. So for example the [i,j] cell of user X and user Y would be some value like 10 if they did the same things 10 times, and 1 if they did the same things 1 time.

I tried running the [cophenetic distances algorithm on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639794/in-r-how-can-i-plot-a-similarity-matrix-like-a-block-graph-after-clustering-d) and this is what I get, and I'm at a loss to see how one can go about picking apart this data more effectively.

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Cophonetic distances]

Comment: This one should be pushed over to http://www.crossvalidated.com as the question is more about interpretation of results rather than specifically a programming question. But there are litterally hundreds of clustering methods available through R. See the task view: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html